# submitting variable from 2 files to php file simultaneously

Tags: php, html, sql

I am currently stuck trying to further improve my search mechanism for my project. I consider myself a novice at PHP.the code below is from my filter.php file

```
<html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../site/assets/css/reset.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../site/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css">
        <form action="search.php" method="GET">
           <div action="search.php" class="filt" >
              <ul >
                  <li onclick="myFunction()" >Offer type</li>
                  <li id="myDIV">
                       <ul>
                          <li><input type="radio" value="all"checked="checked"  name="offertype">all</input></li>
                          <li><input type="radio" value="free" name="offertype">free</input></li>
                          <li><input type="radio" value="trade"name="offertype">trade</input></li>
                          <li><input type="radio" value="sell" name="offertype">sell</input></li>
                        </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li onclick="myFunction2()">Publisher
                   <li id="myDIV2">
                     <input type="search" name="publisher" placeholder="enter publisher name">  
                  </li>
                  </li>

                  <li  onclick="myFunction3()">pricing</li>
                  <li id="myDIV3">

                          <ul>
                          <li><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="price order" value="low">Lowest to Highest</input></li>
                          <li><input type="radio" name="price order" value="high">Highest to Lowest </input></li>

                        </ul>   
                  </li>
                  </li >


              </ul> 

             </div>


         </form>
```

the following is from my Header.PHP file

```
<body>
    <header id="page_header">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="register.php"><li>Signup </li></a>
                <a href="login.php"><li>Login    </li></a>

            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!--Logo-->
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png">
        </div> <!-- End of logo div -->

        <!--search box-->
    <div id="browse">
        <form action="search.php?" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <select name="genre">
                    <option value="" selected>Genre</option>
                    <option value="Programming">Programming</option>
                    <option value="Non-fiction">Non-fiction</option>
                    <option value="Science fiction">Science fiction</option>
                    <option value="Satire">Satire</option>
                    <option value="drama">Drama</option>
                    <option value="Action &#38;"> Action and Adventure</option>


                </select>
                <input type="search" name="bookname" placeholder="Browse Books">
                <input type="submit"  value="Search">
            </fieldset>
        </form><!-- End of search form -->
    </div> <!-- End of seacrch form div -->



    </header>
```

I'm trying to variable from both files simultaneously from the header and filter files. how would i go about doing this?

```
    <?php
include ( "../includes/db_connection.php" );
include ( "../includes/layouts/header.php" );
include( "../includes/layouts/filter.php" );
?>

    <?php

$BOOKNAME =  $_GET['bookname'];
$GENRE    =  $_GET['genre'];
$OFFER    =  $_GET['offertype'];
$PUB      =  $_GET['publisher'];

if(strlen($GENRE )=='0' ) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
    BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%' ";
}
else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM book WHERE  
    BOOKNAME LIKE '$BOOKNAME%' AND GENRE LIKE '$GENRE'
    AND PUBLISHER LIKE '$PUB' ";    
}
$result = $connection->query($sql);

?>
```

Comment: Either use AJAX or have only one form

Comment: why you dont use ajax